# How get download stats in Matomo analytics for static content that's served by my CDN (Cloudflare)?

Tags: analytics, cloudflare, static-content, matomo

I'm considering enabling Cloudflare for my site, which will make it so that static content is loaded from their servers instead of mine. If that's the case, how can I tally the request in our analytics platform for that piece of static content? How can I know how many times it was downloaded?

Currently we handle this server-side. That is, when somebody requests a PDF, we use an API to tally that in our analytics tool. But we'll never see the request at all if things are working properly, so....how to handle this?

Comment: Well Matomo tracks downloads of files automatically. If the URL doesn't have a specific (e.g. .pdf) file ending, you may need to add a class to the link: https://developer.matomo.org/guides/tracking-javascript-guide#download-and-outlink-tracking

Comment: Only if those files are clicked from *our* website. If they're shared and clicked elsewhere Matomo doesn't have any idea. That's why we do server side tracking for these.

Comment: That makes sense. But if you neither control the website people are coming from nor the site delivering the data, you don't really have any data to record.

Comment: There *must* be a solution for this, right? Some kind of API or something? I find it hard to believe that people give up tracking when they enable a CDN.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to get the access.log. Then you could import it into Matomo.